# How to create order in Shopware 6 via API

Tags: php, api, migration, shopware

I am migrating a shop form an old platform to Shopware 6. I need to move over orders and I am having problems doing so. I am using the API that is being called by a script that has access to the old platform database. I have already pushed nearly all other entities (customers, products, media, categories, links between those) using the API and it works fine.
In the documentation it seems one should create a cart first and then via an action create it into an order, then add order address, payment and transition the states via actions to what is required.

There is no exact guide for it so I ended up trying to push a POST request with order data to `order` endpoint like that:

```
array:12 [
  "orderNumber" => "100000546"
  "price" => array:6 [
    "netPrice" => 47.3519
    "totalPrice" => 50.32
    "positionPrice" => 50.32
    "calculatedTaxes" => array:1 [
      0 => array:3 [
        "tax" => 3.314633
        "taxRate" => 7
        "price" => 50.32
      ]
    ]
    "taxRules" => array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "taxRate" => 7
        "percentage" => 100
      ]
    ]
    "taxStatus" => "gross"
  ]
  "shippingCosts" => array:5 [
    "unitPrice" => 4.95
    "totalPrice" => 4.95
    "quantity" => 1
    "calculatedTaxes" => array:1 [
      0 => array:3 [
        "tax" => 0.3465
        "taxRate" => 7
        "price" => 4.95
      ]
    ]
    "taxRules" => array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "taxRate" => 7
        "percentage" => 100
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "billingAddressId" => "9f27c3c98dfe4e47ad2a9493da5807bc"
  "currencyId" => "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca"
  "languageId" => "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b"
  "salesChannelId" => "d1d7fc6faedb4600afd0cfe68f627f6d"
  "orderDateTime" => "2014-11-03 08:27:43"
  "currencyFactor" => 1
  "stateId" => "8089405ce1e046f1819823d847125d25"
  "lineItems" => array:1 [
    0 => array:6 [
      "identifier" => "5158757ba32b489faf70fcd7c4578604"
      "productId" => "5158757ba32b489faf70fcd7c4578604"
      "quantity" => 10
      "label" => "Some product"
      "position" => 1
      "price" => array:5 [
        "unitPrice" => 3.64
        "totalPrice" => 36.3551
        "quantity" => 10
        "calculatedTaxes" => array:1 [
          0 => array:3 [
            "tax" => 0.2548
            "taxRate" => 7
            "price" => 36.3551
          ]
        ]
        "taxRules" => array:1 [
          0 => array:2 [
            "taxRate" => 7
            "percentage" => 100
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "orderCustomer" => array:6 [
    "customerId" => "cafedb542f2f488e99375192092c9032"
    "salutationId" => "08f9cf197c0643ac98590948cf5dd9f8"
    "firstName" => "xx
    "lastName" => "xx
    "email" => "xx
    "customerNumber" => "10020"
  ]
]
```

This creates an order in the database but I cannot see it in the orders listing in admin (`admin#/sw/order/index`) - in fact it breaks the list when I try to change list page. If I open another order and then replace the order id with the one I created I can open it but it does not have the details box. I can see only Items, Status and Documents. I suspected that it is due to the fact that there is no payment and shipment information linked so I added in also `order_address` entity via the API and then tried to create `order_delivery` so I have state for the shipment. Unfortunately I get this when I try to create such entity with a state:

```
    0 => {#8643
      +"code": "FRAMEWORK__WRITE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION"
      +"status": "400"
      +"detail": "This field is write-protected. (Got: "crud" scope and "system" is required)"
      +"template": "This field is write-protected. (Got: "%s" scope and "%s" is required)"
      +"meta": {#8655
        +"parameters": array:2 [
          0 => "crud"
          1 => "system"
        ]
      }
      +"source": {#8664
        +"pointer": "/0/stateIdstateId"
      }
    }
```

And I am stuck. I need help. Can I add some switch to the request to force write (create a token with `system` scope?) into the `stateId` field? Or I should perform action? But then again I cannot perform an action without having `order_delivery` entity already set with value `open`...

Am I doing it right anyways? By trying to create entities directly (these orders serve just as an archive, they are all completed already)?

Answer (score 4):

To create order in Shopware 6 using Admin API you should push POST request to `order` endpoint (https://example.com/api/order).

**Remember** this is only example working on specific Shopware 6 instance (there are individual UUID`s used).

If you want to know how to build body on your Shopware 6 instance, you can read this article: https://macopedia.com/blog/news/how-to-create-a-correct-order-using-admin-api-in-shopware-6

**Example body:**

```
{
  "billingAddressId": "f01a5f849ecc4056af9036bc2e077bb7",
  "currencyId": "763bcef34142422a8f118cf38c9e00ca",
  "salesChannelId": "98432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d",
  "stateId": "f9063cf8c1764db980d8091afc6e8c53",
  "orderDateTime": "2022-06-08 14:51:01",
  "orderNumber": "123456",
  "currencyFactor": 4.33,
  "orderCustomer": {
    "email": "email@example.com",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "salutationId": "ed643807c9f84cc8b50132ea3ccb1c3b",
    "title": null,
    "vatIds": null,
    "company": "Macopedia"
  },
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": "f01a5f849ecc4056af9036bc2e077bb7",
      "salutationId": "ed643807c9f84cc8b50132ea3ccb1c3b",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "street": "Longstreet 3",
      "zipcode": "12345",
      "city": "Warsaw",
      "countryId": "23c2863c6cfd4caf98d77c6572718a53",
      "company": "",
      "vatId": "",
      "phoneNumber": "123 123 123"
    }
  ],
  "price": {
    "totalPrice": 13.98,
    "positionPrice": 13.98,
    "rawTotal": 13.98,
    "netPrice": 13.98,
    "taxStatus": "gross",
    "calculatedTaxes": [
      {
        "tax": 0,
        "taxRate": 0,
        "price": 13.98
      }
    ],
    "taxRules": [
      {
        "taxRate": 0,
        "percentage": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  "shippingCosts": {
    "unitPrice": 2.99,
    "totalPrice": 2.99,
    "quantity": 1,
    "calculatedTaxes": [
      {
        "tax": 0,
        "taxRate": 0,
        "price": 2.99
      }
    ],
    "taxRules": [
      {
        "taxRate": 0,
        "percentage": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "productId": "43b379345e2044e4bab948934e78afcc",
      "referencedId": "43b379345e2044e4bab948934e78afcc",
      "payload": {
        "productNumber": "ff8a107797c946acb3e1c00219236867"
      },
      "identifier": "43b379345e2044e4bab948934e78afcc",
      "type": "product",
      "label": "Blue T-shirt",
      "quantity": 1,
      "position": 1,
      "price": {
        "unitPrice": 10.99,
        "totalPrice": 10.99,
        "quantity": 1,
        "calculatedTaxes": [
          {
            "tax": 0,
            "taxRate": 0,
            "price": 10.99
          }
        ],
        "taxRules": [
          {
            "taxRate": 0,
            "percentage": 100
          }
        ]
      },
      "priceDefinition": {
        "type": "quantity",
        "price": 10.99,
        "quantity": 1,
        "taxRules": [
          {
            "taxRate": 0,
            "percentage": 100
          }
        ],
        "listPrice": null,
        "isCalculated": true,
        "referencePriceDefinition": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "deliveries": [
    {
      "stateId": "7aa03d4157e84cf59ba8f30caa6ce3f8",
      "shippingMethodId": "616746f5d82b4474bc804bd7cb913b11",
      "shippingOrderAddress": {
        "id": "071acbb111e3403d99fa31a509537fb1",
        "salutationId": "ed643807c9f84cc8b50132ea3ccb1c3b",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "street": "Shortstreet 5",
        "zipcode": "12345",
        "city": "Warsaw",
        "countryId": "23c2863c6cfd4caf98d77c6572718a53",
        "phoneNumber": "321 321 312"
      },
      "shippingDateEarliest": "2022-06-08 14:51:01",
      "shippingDateLatest": "2022-06-08 14:51:01",
      "shippingCosts": {
        "unitPrice": 8.99,
        "totalPrice": 8.99,
        "quantity": 1,
        "calculatedTaxes": [
          {
            "tax": 0,
            "taxRate": 0,
            "price": 8.99
          }
        ],
        "taxRules": [
          {
            "taxRate": 0,
            "percentage": 100
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "transactions": [
    {
      "paymentMethodId": "09698e286f394eba8d6fcdfdd72816c1",
      "amount": {
        "unitPrice": 13.98,
        "totalPrice": 13.98,
        "quantity": 1,
        "calculatedTaxes": [
          {
            "tax": 0,
            "taxRate": 0,
            "price": 0
          }
        ],
        "taxRules": [
          {
            "taxRate": 0,
            "percentage": 100
          }
        ]
      },
      "stateId": "fcebe9d8e888458cb2f9984259e16c07"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use migration plugins from Shopware for sw5 & sw6.
They are described there [Migration process](https://docs.shopware.com/en/migration-en/Migrationprocess?category=migration-en/shopware5).
And you can find those plugins on GitHub
https://github.com/shopware/SwagMigrationAssistant
&
https://github.com/shopware/SwagMigrationConnector

Comment: Unfortunately this plugins does not support Magento version 1.8 (thats what the old shop I am importing from is running on), it starts with 1.9.
I am considering downloading it however and making adjustments to work with 1.8, at least the data I need (only the orders).

Comment: It's a pity!
I solved a similar problem in the following way. In the old shop, i prepare all data and send a request to my custom admin API endpoint. Then in my endpoint business logic i can implement everything that i need.